# "+" operator placed as index

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of $(a-b)_+$? In other words, what is meant by the "+" operator when it is placed as an index.
If I am comparing for example two variables $a$ and $b$. So what is the value of $(a-b)_+$ when $a>b$ or $a<b$?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: if $f$ is a function, $f_+$ usually means $f_+ (x) = max (f(x),0)$

Comment: The meaning is usually the same for any real number: $x_+ = \max (x, 0)$, so that $x = x_+ - x_-$ and $|x| = x_+ + x_-$.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answers :)))

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 I suggest you use the answer box (and not the comment box) for answers.